# What is meant by building a library?

Tags: build

I downloaded an open source library. It asked me to execute this file called "do" with the command ./do. Then it kept building the library for about 10 min. What is building a library exactly?

Comment: You can accept ( tick ) any of the answers below if it has resolved your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building means compiling the source code to an executable format. A library is a term used to define reusable components.

For example, if you want to do some date conversion operations like dd/mm/yyyy format to mm/dd/yyyy, you can either write your own code or you can use re usable code which is already written by someone.  Those reusable codes can be released to the public in many license forms; one of them is open source.

If the code is open source, the source code will be available for anyone to download. Sometimes the compiled version of the source code will also be there. Instructions will also be provided how to compile ( in other words , "build" ) the source code to an executable format which can be used in your code and that's what it means by "building" a library.

For an example, see the [Joda-Time](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/) Java library.

Answer (score 1):

Building is the process which encompasses source generation (for YACC, Qt MOC etc.), compilation of source code and linking of resulting object files. In brief: it's the sequence of operations that turn human readable source code into a machine-readable binary library.

Pro tip: read the description of the tag `build` under your question.